# Why `import numpy as np` for scientific computing?

Tags: python, numpy

**Why do scientists bother with the `np` for `numpy`**?

(Note this is more a "philosophical"/reasoning question - let us assume that you get your code to perform as intended regardless of choice of syntax)

When I write code for scientific applications, mathematical functions such as `sqrt`, as well as arrays and the many other features of Numpy are "bread and butter" - ubiquitous and taken for granted. For this reason, I always use

```
from numpy import *
```

instead of

```
import numpy as np
```

despite nearly every online example I see. Indeed, a colleague of mine who found my code useful said that they had to go through it and insert `np` everywhere. And yet, why bother? I can honestly say that in the thousands of lines of Python I've written, those three characters would have been redundant and a waste of my time. And that time is not trivial: as stated in many SE discussions, programmer time is more valuable than CPU time. If you want a super optimized program, use `C` or `Fortran` for HPC instead of `python`.

Using

```
from numpy import sqrt
```

is also an option, but also has drawbacks for rapidly making a script where you might want to use a new function out of the blue (as you would in `C`, `Fortran`, `Matlab`, whatever).

Suppose that there is a library for accurately calculating the square root of a complex number - then it's still faster to `import complxlib as cplx`, use `cplx.sqrt` when necessary and `sqrt` the other 99% of the time. So is there a real example or argument as to why my approach is bad practice?

Please note that the question is specifically about `numpy` - a staple in scientific application of python, rather than e.g. `super_esoteric_library8472`.

Comment: In my opinion this is off topic here, anyway try to answer. Simply for clarity and avoid conflict.
This is quite similar to c++ namespace where is better to use `std::cout`.
If I see `np.sqrt` I know without error the exact function and there is not conflict also in future.

Comment: In your example the prefered use would be ``from numpy import sqrt`` instead of ``from numpy import *``. Unless you know **all** the functions that numpy is importing the second might cause you trouble.

Comment: `from scipy import *; from numpy import *; log(1j)` — 200 lines of code below you will wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: @homocomputeris As stated in OP, import every module *other* than `numpy` by name. So, said problem would never occur.

Comment: there are a lot of debates for having or not having `using namespace std` in C++ code by default - for a standard C++ library. Why should the same controversial exclusive approach apply to a non-standard (but of course very popular) package `numpy`?

Comment: Debates about coding styles are at least as old as the Internet. It would make the question a lot more constructive if you were more precise about your criteria for evaluating a coding style, especially since they obviously don't match other people's criteria. Is saving characters really the ultimate goal? "Explicit is better than implicit" is at least as good a principle as saving characters (and I'd say better). Otherwise it is far too easy to end up talking past each other or accidentally start a flame war, which nobody would like.

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan Why import all from NumPy if a project uses, say, SciPy, SymPy or FFTW more? If you want to save typing time, you can `from numpy import sqrt as s`.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that if there is one package that a project is using most heavily than one should import* that project only and then there won't be ambiguity? (fwiw: comparison of different languages python/julia/matlab https://cheatsheets.quantecon.org/)

Answer (score 8):

I would say, that it can be explained by the following famous programming principle:

> Explicit is better than implicit

Usually, that is applied to types; however, it can be applied to namespaces (as mentioned by @Mauro Vanzetto) as well as particular libraries/packages.

I, personally, like having `np.sqrt` or `std::cout` (as opposed to just `sqrt` and `cout`) because typing that does not cost me a lot and I can feel sure that no tricky variable/function hiding can happen and explicitly see if I am using a function coming from a certain namespace/library/package.

In scientific computing, in particular, when even the order of summation can change the result significantly in some cases, I want to avoid a certain type of problems, to begin with – and simplify my life in debugging by explicitly pointing to where each function I am using is coming from.

Comment: The Mathworks apparently disagrees, ha ha.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, they sure can :) That principle is not a dogma and certainly can be argued.

Comment: Is it "better", though? I use a numpy math function maybe once a line on average. This means thousands of $\texttt{np.}$, much less clear code, e.g. $\texttt{np.cos(np.log(x))}$ for a simple compound math function - therefore less clarity for people reading it, debugging etc.

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan for me, `np.cos(np.log(x))` is preferred to `cos(log(x))` in python for the aforementioned reasons. However, there are reasons why some people might disagree. Good thing is that there are language syntax features that allow for both approaches.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Yes, as stated in the OP, both work in principle. I guess my question would be: has it ever, in practice, made a difference for you? If yes, please give a concrete example. If no, you have wasted 0.5 seconds or whatever every time you've typed $\texttt{np.}$, created less readable code *etc etc*.

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan not from Python, but see this example which I personally stumbled upon multiple times, especially applied to complex numbers and code mixture of C/C++. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21392627/2452869    Errors caused by such things are extremely hard to find.

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan you can use `from numpy import log, cos` if that is used that much. The point is that you are trying to keep the namespace clean that, say, matlab is an absolute disaster

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan Note that `numpy` does contain functions which shadow python builtins, which can affect performance (`sum`) or syntax (`max`) and I have seen the last one cause a serious, hard to debug issue.

Comment: @origimbo Thank you, this is the first answer I've seen that I believe has a demonstrable point - I would love to know the details in a full answer, if the question hadn't been locked. After posting the OP, I was considering making a concrete comparison of `numpy` and builtin functions to see precisely how many overlap (results would not remain valid indefinitely, of course).

Comment: @origimbo is right. numpy max and regular max is an extremely good example of where that could be dangerous.